# How to use trained neural network in different platform/technology?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, neural-network

Given I trained a simple neural network using Tensorflow and Python on my laptop and I want to use this model on my phone in C++ app.

Is there any compatibility format I can use? What is the minimal framework *to run* neural networks (not to train)?

**UDP.** I'm also interested in Tensorflow to NOT-Tensorflow compatibility. Do I need to build it up from scratch or there're any best practices?

Comment: which operating system your phone has

Comment: @NuOneTAttygalle it does not matter. I'm asking in general sense and targeting apps on any system. The question is about mobility/compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you don't need a framework at all. A conventional fully connected neural network is simple enough that you can implement it in straight C++. It's about 100 lines of code for the matrix multiplication and a dozen or so for the non-linear activation function.

The biggest part is figuring out how to parse a serialized Tensorflow model, especially given that there are quite a few ways to do so. You probably will want to *freeze* your TensorFlow model; this inserts the weights from the latest training into the model.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you are using iOS or Android. Depending on your  specific needs, you have a choice between TensorFlow for Mobile and TensorFlow Lite

https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/

In particular, to load pre-trained models 
https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models

Comment: thanks. What about Tensorflow to NOT Tensorflow? Any common formats?

Comment: @Ribtoks why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: no reinventing. Just don't like Tensorflow vendor lock.